# Amazon root certificate pinning in Flutter, Dart

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, ssl, certificate-pinning

I'm using AWS CA to generate an SSL certificate for ElasticBeanstalk that I'm using in my Flutter app.
Based on the [bets practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-bestpractices.html#best-practices-pinning), I'm trying to pin HTTP client the Root certificate  from [Amazon Trusted Services](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/)

I face 2 issues with the Flutter HTTP client:

1. Whenever I try to load the certificate it crashes:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: TlsException: Failure trusting builtin roots (OS Error: BAD_PKCS12_DATA(pkcs8_x509.c:657), errno = 0)
```

This is the certificate I use (one of five, I add them all):

```
final _awsRoot1 = _decodePEM("""-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----""");
```

And this is what I do to decode `PEM` :

```
Uint8List _decodePEM(pem) {
  for (var s in _startsWith) {
    if (pem.startsWith(s)) pem = pem.substring(s.length);
  }
  for (var s in _endsWith) {
    if (pem.endsWith(s)) pem = pem.substring(0, pem.length - s.length);
  }
  pem = pem.replaceAll('\n', '');
  pem = pem.replaceAll('\r', '');
  return Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(pem));
}
```

And add it via:

```
void certificatePinningPem(SecurityContext context) {
  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_awsRoot1);
  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_awsRoot2);
  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_awsRoot3);
  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_awsRoot4);
  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_awsRoot5);
}
```

*I get the same exception when I read `DER` file* :

```
final aws1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/cer/aws1.cer');
context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(aws1.buffer.asUint8List());
```

2. PEM file from the connection is different

*Despite that, when I use `badCertificateCallback`, `pem` file from the certificate doesn't match any of those five from [repo](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/)* So how to get **Root certificate** from connection?

```
httpClient.badCertificateCallback = (
      X509Certificate certificate,
      String host,
      int port,
    ) {
      print('Bad certificate: ${certificate.pem} for host $host:$port');
      return false;
    };
```

***Any suggestion on how to properly do certificate pinning in Flutter with AWS Root certificates?***

I found a few related threads but they don't really help, i.e.  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39190#issuecomment-693315205